# Right Frame URL not displaying

Tags: community, mydomain

Using a My Domain login page, I want to display customized content in the right side.

I made a simple page on one of our public Salesforce Communities.  I confirmed that this works and displays correctly in a browser that is not logged in to Salesforce.

However, that same URL shows blank when used as the Right Frame URL for the My Domain login.

Suggestions?

Comment: Any JavaScript erros in browsers developer tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: in the community, disable clickjack protection and re-publish.